# Where should I place input/output console for server?

Tags: linux, networking, console, vps

I'm developing a simple 2d online game and now I'm designing my server. The server will be run on linux vps and I need a way to communicate with it (for example to close it, and as it will be run on vps, simply closing terminal won't work). So I think there are 2 options:

1) Write 2 apllications - server which doesn't say anything and doesn't accept console input and the second application is console which sends commands to server (like exit, get online players etc).

2) Write 1 application which has 2 threads - one is the real server, the second thread will be used for cin and cout. However I'm not sure if this will work on vps...

Or maybe there is better aproach? What is the usual way of doing this?
Remember that it must be vps-compatible way (only ssh access to it).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a "daemon" (server) for the main server function and then use a secondary application that can connect to the server and send it commands.

Or just use regular signals, like most other servers do - when you reconfigure your Apache server, for example, you send it a SIGHUP signal that restarts the server. That way, you don't need a second application at all - just "kill -SIGHUP your_server_pid".

Comment: Everyone recommends me the "deamon" way so I will go for it. I didn't know about sighup, it seems it is the ideal solution! Thank you.